# Java NullPointerException in .containsKey

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm very new to Java. Trying to access a field in the HashMap `observationMap`, and am told there is a `NullPointerException` when I check if the `HashMap` contains the key. In particular, in the `getEventSpeed()` method.

`.containsKey()` should return NULL, so not clear how this line causes issue for the if statement?

Thank you for your help

```
public class IsDrivingObservation {

  private Map<String,String> observationMap;

  public String getEventSpeed() {
    if (observationMap.containsKey("eventSpeed")) {
      return observationMap.get("eventSpeed");
    }
    return "foo";
  }

  public void setEventSpeed(String speed) {
    observationMap.put("eventSpeed", speed);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you never create the `observationMap`. Try this:

```
private Map<String,String> observationMap = new HashMap<>();
```

otherwise you will get the `NPE` in both of your methods. 
That depends on which method you call first.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you for prompt response. Seems obvious now.

Comment: @Natasha whitney glad to help you. feel free to acxcept my answer with a click on the white hook top left of my answer.